# SQL Server database storing 'ć' as 'c'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to store a balkan surname in my sql server db but when I try and update a recordes using the following SQL:

```
update User_Data
set name = 'Kramarić'
where User_PKID= 3047
```

However when I query the db with:

```
select name from User_Data where User_PKID = 3047
```

it returns:

```
Kramaric
```

Any idea on how I can get it to store it in its original form. I need it as such as I do a string comparison on my server code with data coming from a website and if the 'ć' isn't the same it fails.

Comment: Have you tried using nvarahar?

This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038213/which-special-characters-are-allowed-in-sql-server-varchar-fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What **datatype** is your column `name`? It should be `NVARCHAR` to handle Unicode characters.

And you also must use the `N'...'` prefix to specify Unicode strings:

```
UPDATE dbo.User_Data
SET name = N'Kramarić'
WHERE User_PKID= 3047
```

Answer (score 1):

See [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530)

```
update User_Data
set name = N'Kramarić'
where User_PKID= 3047
```