# Insert special character ° using python and mssql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

In Python and MSSQL, using pyodc Im trying to create a column in the table with the name Azimuth °, but when Im create the line :

```
cmd = (" CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "_fly" +" ("
" [Azimuth (°)] float,"
") ")
```

the table its created but with this name in the header:
Azimuth (Â°)

any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not name your columns something more usable for sql like simply "Azimuth". You can add the special characters and such when displaying the column. A column name like that would make me want to kill myself being forced to type in queries.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038213/which-special-characters-are-allowed-in-sql-server-varchar-fields

And for your query, you might want to use a Python library to build your CREATE TABLE... i.e. http://pymssql.org/en/latest/

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your answers, I'm trying to "migrate" from an old VB6 that reads an excel file and upload all table into mssql automatically.  Since Im learning python I though it was a good exercise to practice. I want to be as close as possible in the SQL because from that SQL table there are so many other processes that maybe look for example "Azimuth (°)" .  I'll check all your suggestions  Thanks

Comment: Thank you, used the pymssql and coding utf-8 and works like a charm!!

Answer (score 2):

**Update (February 2019):** This appears to no longer be an issue with pyodbc, at least under Python_3. pyodbc 4.0.25 creates the table with the correct column name.

---

*(Original answer)*

I was able to reproduce your issue using pyodbc, even when specifying `utf-8` as my source encoding.

However, I did get the correct result using [pymssql](http://www.pymssql.org/):

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymssql

cnxn = pymssql.connect(
    server='localhost',
    port='52865',
    user='sa',
    password='whatever',
    database='myDb',
    autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

sql = """\
CREATE TABLE tableName_fly (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Azimuth (°)] FLOAT
    )
"""
crsr.execute(sql)

crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Ah, then it might be a problem in unixODBC. Nice work.

Comment: I did the tests on a Windows box so unixODBC was not involved. It looks more like a pyodbc "thing". (But thanks for the compliment anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but it might be helpful to know that the Azimuth character ° is a supported identifier in `MSSQL`.

The rules for valid database identifiers is mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), you can select your matching DB version. 
The Azimuth character is a Unicode character, part of the 3.2 standard library under the [Latin-1_Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement) block.

Comment: Sorry, no. `[Azimuth (°)]` may be an *inadvisable* column name in SQL Server, but it is not *illegal*. I just created such a column in SQL Server 2008 R2 using SSMS.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my horrible mistake @GordThompson.